# function pointer to a different class member

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers

I have the following problem:

```
class A
{
public:
   A()
   {}
   int foo(int a)
   {
      return a;
   }
};

class B
{
private:
   int (A::*pFoo)(int);
public:
   B(int (A::*_pFoo)(int))
  {
     this->pFoo = _pFoo;
  }
     int cFoo(int i)
  {
     this->pFoo(i); //this causes a problem the compiler says it's not a pointer
  }
};

A a;
B b(&A::foo);
```

I've tried already

```
int (*pFoo)(int)
```

instead of

```
int (A::*pFoo)(int)
```

but then there are problems with the constructor
and when I used `B b(&a.foo)` there is a compiler error which says that I have to use `B b(&A::foo)`

Comment: Fix the syntax errors in your code, please.

Answer (score 1):

You trying to call `A:foo` for an object of type `B` but a pointer to a member function of `A` requires an instance of `A`.

Instead of saving another pointer or reference to `A` inside `B` you can redesign your code for `B` to be a little more generic:

```
#include <functional>
struct A
{
  int foo(int a)
  {
    return a;
  }
};

class B
{
private:
  std::function<int(int)> pfoo;
public:
  B(std::function<int(int)> foofunc) 
    : pfoo(foofunc) { }
  int cFoo(int i)
  {
    return pfoo(i); 
  }
};
```

Now `B` can take any function pointer returning `int` with one `int` argument and you can just bind a function pointer for `A::foo` with an instance of `A`:

```
A my_a;
B my_b(std::bind(&A::foo, my_a, std::placeholders::_1));

my_b.cFoo(2); // works
```

[See it on ideone.](http://ideone.com/uVkyhI)

Answer (score 0):

You miss a closing parenthesis in B's constructor:

```
B(int (A::*_pFoo)(int))
```

Correct syntax of calling via member function pointer is:

```
(this->*pFoo)(i);
```

Comment: I've tried it but it says: expression preceding parentheses of appearent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

Answer (score 0):

You have many syntax errors even before getting to the pointer thing.

working example:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f8fb012496548e0

1) you miss parenthesis on the c.tor

```
B(int (A::*_pFoo)(int))
```

2) your classes does not end well, they need `;` in their closing braces:

```
class A{};
```

3) you don't have any main.

4) you activate pFoo wrong. think about it a little. if `pFoo` is a pointer to `A` member function, can you really activate it from `B` pointer? becuase this is what `this` points at, `B` class. you need to activate pFoo with `A` pointer.

```
A* a = nullptr;
return (a->*pFoo)(i);
```

5. not entirely syntax error, but its the best you ident your code properly.

Comment: Of course, you'll need to initialize `A* a` too before dereferencing it for the call.

Comment: it dependce. if pFoo does not excess any class members, it can be nullptr.

Comment: According to the language specification, doing that will have undefined behaviour. That said, it will probably appear to work as intended in most implementations. If the function does not access any members, then I don't think there's any reason for it to be non-static though.